# UIButton and swipe-to-delete on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a UIButton. 
UIButton blocks the swipe-to-delete gesture recognizer implemented by Apple; if the swipe starts on the button, the swipe is not recognized, otherwise the delete button appears and everything works correctly

At the moment,  I have replace the UIButton by an UIImageView to get the desired behaviour.

I would like if somebody manages to make this work.

I have already tried to implement this delegate method

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

and searched the view/subviews for all its gesture recognizers and assign them the cell as delegate. I still can make it work with a UIButton.

I target ios8

Thanks

Comment: That's weird. The behavior I was seeing a few days ago with this exact case was that the swipe was recognized but the button would also fire when I took the finger off of it. It might be because my button was huge. But the way I solved it was to get rid of the button and use a tap gesture recognizer on an image.

Comment: Is your action touch up inside?

Comment: Yes my button is build in the storyboard file

Answer (score 0):

Use UILable or UIImage instead of UIButton, and set userInteractionEnabled to YES, and add a UITapGestureRecognizer gesture to it.